# cursor program generating sqlexception ordinal binding and named binding cannot be combined

Tags: plsql, cursor, callable-statement

I have created a program using CallableStatement and Cursors to fetch the records from a table named Student with names starting from 'A' with pl/sql procedures.The program is giving an SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!
please help me out to resolve this..

the procedure is:

```
create or replace procedure get_StudDetails(mycur out sys_refcursor,cond in varchar)
as
begin
open mycur for
select * from Student where stname like cond;
end;
/
```

the java program is:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
class CursorTest
{
public static void main(String s[])
{
try
{
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","rt","pwdd");
CallableStatement cs=con.prepareCall("{call get_StudDetails(?,?)}");
cs.getString(2+"A%");
cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.execute();
System.out.println("procedure invoked");
ResultSet rs=(ResultSet)cs.getObject(1);
while(rs.next())
{
System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3)+"\t"+rs.getString(4));
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getString` but `setString` instead:

```
CallableStatement cs=con.prepareCall("{call get_StudDetails(?,?)}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.setString(2, "A%");
cs.execute();
```

Comment: @Vikalp If it helped you then please accept and upvote the answer.